# Change text of blue bar that shows "APP NAME is using your location" on home screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I'm using location manager, requestWhenInUse authorization. When my app goes into the background, the blue bar appears that shows "App name is using your Location".

Can I change this text to something else?

Or is there any other way to display the text on home screen.

[image][image]

But how does UBER shows this?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: Uber creates a fake audio recorder, and uses UIKit/UIApplication.h private methods to modify the appearance and text of the double height status bar.**

---

I have actually been investigating this, as I too would like to implement this is my app. Firstly, the Uber Partner app is an enterprise app, so Private API's may be in use. That said, here is what I have found whilst looking:

Firstly, the text in the bar is located in a json language localisation file in the Uber Partner app:

i.stack.imgur.com/rYoaD.png

The relevant language file is then retrieved in the UberDriver binary, by the [UBPingControllerDriver updateDoubleHeightStatusBar] method.

i.stack.imgur.com/e9WyY.png

The actual double height status bar is carried out by the method [UBFakeAudioRecorder sharedInstance], which creates a fake audio recorder (most likely dumps the output in /dev/null). However, this gives a red bar. So the app then uses a separate method [UBFakeAudioRecorder shouldRecordWithLocationPermission:] to use the location permission to create the blue bar.

i.stack.imgur.com/M1j5D.png

The actual text is set using a selector called @selector(setDoubleHeightStatusText:forStyle:); located in [UBPingControllerDriver updateDoubleHeightStatusBar]_block_invoke

i.stack.imgur.com/HWTVw.png

The final screenshot interacts with a UIApplication instance, <s>and I've no idea what goes on after that.</s> The Uber app uses UIKit, and interfaces with **@interface UIApplication (Private)** to modify the status bar properties. A full list of the headers can be found here: **https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIApplication.h**, but from a brief look, I would guess they are using:

**- (void)setDoubleHeightMode:(int)arg1 glowAnimationEnabled:(BOOL)arg2;**

**- (void)setDoubleHeightStatusText:(id)arg1 forStyle:(int)arg2;**

**- (void)addStatusBarStyleOverrides:(int)arg1;**

and possibly a few others...

Comment: Why the downvote? At least leave a comment if you believe what I have said is wrong and correct me.

Comment: Also, if you are looking to use this method of implementing the custom status bar, you can also use the 'request Always authorisation' and manually trigger the double height bar.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could change your app name but the rest is fixed.

If you use request Always authorization you won't get the blue bar.  If you stop the location manager before being sent into the background or when the app resigns active, you won't get the blue bar either.

Comment: I've updated my question. Have a look at it. I'm pretty sure UBER also use request when in use authorization to show this.

Comment: I didn't think that was possible.

Comment: There has to be a way then.

Answer (score -2):

I think You can't change text on the bar.

Comment: Of course it is possible. There are apps doing it, as in the question (the Uber Partner app does it, but it's an Enterprise app not an App Store app).